# Metal: vertexFunction defined in .metal file becomes nil once setting Compiler and Linker Options for MSL cikernel

Tags: swift, metal, cifilter, cikernel

VertexFunction and FragmentFunction defined in .metal file worked nicely, but they became nil once I specified Compiler and Linker Options following [Apple's doc](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/coreimage/cikernel/2880194-kernelwithfunctionname): -fcikernel flag in the Other Metal Compiler Flags option, and -cikernel flat in MTLLINKER_FLAGS in User-Defined setting.

I need the settings above for cikernel with MSL (metal shading language). Indeed, cikernel with Core Image Kernel Language deprecated in 12.0.

How could I use both vertex/fragment Metal shader and MSL cikernel together?

```
let library = self.device?.makeDefaultLibrary()!
let pipeLineDescriptor = MTLRenderPipelineDescriptor()
pipeLineDescriptor.vertexFunction=library.makeFunction(name: "myVertexShader")
pipeLineDescriptor.fragmentFunction=library.makeFunction(name: "myFragmentShader")
```

Comment: Hello! Have you found a solution for [this](http://5.9.10.113/54250944/contentsscale-does-not-improve-image-quality-of-calayer-in-avvideocompositioncor)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I guess you have to compile your filter kernels separately instead of with your default Metal library.

To do so, you could for instance give them another file extension, like `.kernel` and add a custom *Build Rule* like so:

[image]

Then add a custom *Build Phase* that copies the compiled kernel metallibs into your app bundle:

[image]

To initialize the `CIKernel` with the correct metal source, you can do something like this:

```
let url = Bundle(for: type(of: self)).url(forResource: "<#name of your .kernel file#>", withExtension: "metallib")!
let data = try! Data(contentsOf: url)
let kernel = try! CIKernel(functionName: "<#kernel function name#>", fromMetalLibraryData: data)
```

(Note that you should remove the compiler and liker flags again from your project settings to have your other Metal sources compile properly again.)

Comment: Thank you, Frank!  .kernel extension didn't work so I changed it to */cikernel.metal, but then your solution works perfectly. Just one question..., why we need -c option in xcrun metal? Apple's doc didn't have this option, but the script fails without it.

Comment: According to the command line help it's `Only run preprocess, compile, and assemble steps`. And honestly I don't know why it's required, I just read the logs of what the default Metal build phase does and copied what was needed… ¯\_(ツ)_/¯

Comment: d(>_･ )☆☆great!

Comment: OMG @Frank I almost had a heart attack thinking my CIKernels were gone. But I followed the video, and your answer, and eventually got there. Both `SCNProgram` and `CIFIlters` working together. Awesome! Video:https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2020/10021/

Answer (score 1):

An update of Frank Schlegel's answer that works in Xcode 11, where, as Giraff Wombat mentions, the metal compiler simply ignores input files that don't end in `.metal`. To make sure the CI kernel file stays out of the regular metal pipeline's way, I made the extension "`.mcikernel`" and put for the build rule script:

```
mkdir -p ${DERIVED_FILES_DIR}/kernels
cp ${INPUT_FILE_PATH} ${DERIVED_FILES_DIR}/${INPUT_FILE_BASE}.metal
xcrun metal -fcikernel ${DERIVED_FILES_DIR}/${INPUT_FILE_BASE}.metal -c -o ${DERIVED_FILES_DIR}/kernels/${INPUT_FILE_BASE}.air
xcrun metallib -cikernel -o ${DERIVED_FILES_DIR}/kernels/${INPUT_FILE_BASE}.metallib ${DERIVED_FILES_DIR}/kernels/${INPUT_FILE_BASE}.air
```

Comment: yes，this is right way, metal compile system will ignore non .metal file, and will produce nothing.

Answer (score 1):

I was not able to get either of the existing Answers working (AlterEgo answer seems incomplete, like doesn't show input/output file settings).

In any event, the [WWDC video](https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2020/10021), Apple recommends the following.

Create a Metal file called something like MyKernels.ci.metal with:

```
#include <metal_stdlib>
using namespace metal;

#include <CoreImage/CoreImage.h>
 
extern "C" float4 do_nothing(coreimage::sample_t s) {
    return s;
}
```

Next add two Build Rules, both of them uncheck "Run once per architecture". Rule 1:

```
Source Files with names matching:
*.ci.metal

xcrun metal -c -I $MTL_HEADER_SEARCH_PATHS -fcikernel "${INPUT_FILE_PATH}" -o "${SCRIPT_OUTPUT_FILE_0}"

output files:
$(DERIVED_FILE_DIR)/$(INPUT_FILE_BASE).air
```

Second:

```
Source Files with names matching:
*.ci.air

xcrun metallib -cikernel "${INPUT_FILE_PATH}" -o "${SCRIPT_OUTPUT_FILE_0}"

output files:
$(METAL_LIBRARY_OUTPUT_DIR)/$(INPUT_FILE_BASE).metallib
```

To use:

```
let url = Bundle.main.url(forResource: "MyKernels", withExtension: "ci.metallib")!
let data = try! Data(contentsOf: url)
kernel = try! CIColorKernel(functionName: "do_nothing", fromMetalLibraryData: data)
```

Note that other answers that suggest adding the `fckernel` and `cikernel` flags to the `Build Settings` are not recommended. They will cause an issue if regular Metal is being used and possibly other issues. This solution will only use those flags on files with the `.ci.metal` extension.

Screenshot of the Build Rules:

[image]

Comment: xcode 13 seems to have broken this method for me :(

Comment: fix for xcode 13 was to remove the `-I $MTL_HEADER_SEARCH_PATHS` as stated [here](https://developer.apple.com/forums/thread/688644)