# One default MTLLibrary from multiple .metal files (compute kernel and CIKernel implementations)?

Tags: swift, ios13, metal, core-image, cikernel

In migrating custom Core Image filter kernels to Metal Shading Language, I encountered an error with building the default Metal library (default.metallib):

```
metallib: error: exactly one input file required
```

I was under the impression these could be in separate .metal files. Attempting to merge them into one file leads to this error:

```
Metal library creation failed: Error Domain=MTLLibraryErrorDomain Code=3 "Filters module must contain no vertex/fragment/kernel functions but contains 1 kernel function"
```

Namespacing to `metal` and to `coreimage` prevent the compute kernel from showing up as an available function in the default library.

Found this SO answer, which recommends building separate libraries:

[Metal: vertexFunction defined in .metal file becomes nil once setting Compiler and Linker Options for MSL cikernel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57391441/metal-vertexfunction-defined-in-metal-file-becomes-nil-once-setting-compiler-a)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can’t use the default Metal build pipeline for compiling multiple `.metal` files containing Core Image kernels into one library right now. The linker doesn’t allow merging multiple `.air` files into one `.metallib` when setting the `-cikernel` flag.

You either have to put all your kernels into one `.metal` file or use the solution I posted in the answer you linked to above.

Comment: Thank you for your reply! What's the correct way to merge the files? I tried keeping the compute function the same (top-level scope), and adding the CIKernel functions using the `extern "C" { namespace coreimage { // implementation } }` namespacing, but encountered the error "Filters module must contain no vertex/fragment/kernel functions but contains 1 kernel function". Couldn't find any documentation on how to namespace the compute function.

Comment: Oh, I guess you can’t mix “regular” Metal shaders with Core Image kernels because CI kernels require special treatment. You’d have to compile them into different libs, I guess…

Answer (score 1):

You may create multiple `Foo.metal` and `Bar.metal` files.
Just don't add them as linker targets.

Instead `#include "Foo.metal"` and `#include "Bar.metal"` in a `Main.metal` file.
And only add the `Main.metal` file as linker target.

That way there is only one `.metal` file, which includes all the other `.metal` files. Simple.

---

Therefore the content of the `Main.metal` file may very simply look like:

```
#include "Foo.metal"
#include "Bar.metal"
```